# HTML5 localStorage as condition tool to change CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html, local-storage

**Hi**

I have tried to solve this for some time I think I'm doing everything right but can't get it work. Any and all suggestions or ideas are welcome.

Im trying to change the display property from :none to :block on an external css style sheet dependent on if the value of a localstorage key is equal to null using jQuery.

CSS

```
 #cart-totals div.greysp1{
 display:none; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 3px 0;margin: 0 0 0 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align:left;
 line-height:18px;
 color:#888;}
```

Javascript/jquery

```
if(localStorage.getItem('userScribble')==null){  

       $("#cart-totals div.greysp1").css("display","block");

       console.log("null");

    }else{
      console.log("Not null")

     }
```

Html

```
 <div id="cart-totals" >
             <div class="cart-totals-content">
                          <div class="greysp1">
                            <div class="fL">Merchandise Subtotal:</div>
                            <div class="fR" id="MerchSubTotal"></div>
                          </div>

            </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas?

I haven't found any other examples of this. If you know of any let me know

Comment: Where's the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/C68np/2

Comment: I think you may have the logic reversed here - are you trying to display an element if the localStorage variable exists or hide it? Because your code, which looks to be exactly the same in yckarts jsFiddle, is actually hiding the element if the LS variable exists.

Comment: Alternative solution: [HTML5 localStorage: Big JSON, specific value as condition to change CSS (favorite list)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776575/html5-localstorage-big-json-specific-value-as-condition-to-change-css-favorit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code does not seem to work in your tests, then the probable reason is that you are testing it locally on a browser (e.g. IE 9) that does not support `localStorage` for local documents. (Sounds paradoxical, but the behavior is understandable because `localStorage` is defined per domain name, and for local documents there is no domain.)

So test it e.g. on Chrome (or newest version of Firefox), or upload the file onto a web server and test from there.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am using the latest vs of Chrome and I can see the values and keys from the resources screen in the developer tools So I know i'm setting local storage correctly. The example I showed is a striped down version. A more complete example is at http://jsfiddle.net/4CvNz/2/